# How to find maximum Value in JDE (RDA)

Tags: jdeveloper, jdedwards

I would like to knew how can I find the maximum value in column in JDE Solution? Would you mind to show me the way to do it? Because I am not able to do it by using JDE RDA.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by:

> ..i not able to do it by using JDE RDA..

You don't know how to use it or you're using the FDA?

Well, in RDA you can use the Aggregate **Maximum Of**, doing a Level Break on the column you want the maximum value.

On FDA you need to code your logic, something like:

```
MaxValue = 0
Begin Loop through the table
  If table.column_you_want > MaxValue
    MaxValue = table.column_you_want
  End If
End Loop
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. when i use aggregate function in RDA the result i get no able to display. Besides that, i already try other way such as sort the column in descending order. Unfortunately, the result i get will be duplicate.

Comment: If you're no way out, make an auxiliary section only to do that, create a Level Break on the column you want and use the aggregate function, then on the main section call the auxiliary. Good Luck!

Comment: hello bro,i done it already by sort the column in descending order and always take the top 1 value. As feedback when using aggregate function the item no able to display with only one maximum value. For example, let say the column consist of 4 different value it will display all in once time. I think may be is my level break logical error, i will try to resolve it by using the method you recommended. Anyway thank you for your suggestion. (^^)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, if you are looking to find the next available ID to use in your table, there is already a concept well implemented in JDE to keep track of the next unique id for a table or even a process.

Unique id for a table
Look at the program P00022 which hold a next number by table. There is the business function X00022 you can use in your report to retrieve the value.

Unique ID for a process
Look at the program P0002 which holds next numbers by modules for specific document type. Use the business function X0002 to access the values in your RDA.